# Reading a binary(ASN1) file in python

Tags: python, hex, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read a binary file and saving it in a new hex file, but without success. Basically I want to read the binary, convert it to hex and find a particular value in it.

Here what I'm trying :

```
>>> g = open('full_file.dat', 'rb')
>>> g.read(10)
'\xb4\x82\x01\x19\x80\x01\x12\x83\x08B'
>>> g.close()
```

I tried numpy as well and creating a list, but didn't manage to get the outuput I wanted.that's the output of my list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.fromfile('full_file.dat')
>>> arr_1 = np.fromfile('full_file.dat', dtype='uint8')
>>> arr_2 = np.fromfile('full_file.dat', dtype='uint16')
>>> arr_3 = np.fromfile('full_file.dat', dtype='uint32')
>>> arr_4 = np.fromfile('full_file.dat', dtype='uint64')
>>> arr[0:0+10]
array([-7.04819856e-294,  2.41220765e-196,  1.42312203e-132,
       -7.21283195e+014, -3.91818329e-273,  1.93670867e-296,
        1.55576471e-154,  1.60149121e-137,  7.95805944e-067,
        6.63806646e+246])
>>> arr_1[0:0+10]
array([180, 130,   1,  25, 128,   1,  18, 131,   8,  66], dtype=uint8)
>>> arr_2[0:0+10]
array([33460,  6401,   384, 33554, 16904, 24832,  2064,  5970, 34041,
       21256], dtype=uint16)
>>> arr_3[0:0+10]
array([ 419529396, 2198995328, 1627406856,  391251984, 1393067257,
        613427589, 2769310728, 3271852038, 2250748950, 2271278338],
      dtype=uint32)
>>> arr_4[0:0+10]
array([ 9444613018236322484,  1680414477402522120,  2634651434612196601,
       14052497503330259976,  9755066184073982998,   182770718416065793,
        2306036527631311257,  2560251140755162795,  3617925914634227596,
        8299678268708451374], dtype=uint64)
```

I'm new to python and using python 2.7

My expectation was to see what I can see using this online tool(file attached), i.e.

[Opening the file with a online tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqyT.png)

Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: When you open a file with `rb` you're reading it as bytes, you can convert the bytes to hex like this `g.read(10).hex()` at that point the 10 bytes you've read are in a hex string which you should be able to search through.

Comment: Hey Grizzle, thanks, well, I did what you suggested, it works just for python 3, having said that, that's the output. >>> g = open('full_file.dat', 'rb')
>>> g.read(10)
b'\xb4\x82\x01\x19\x80\x01\x12\x83\x08B'
>>> g.close()
--------
>>> g = open('full_file.dat', 'rb')
>>> g.read(10).hex()
'b4820119800112830842'
>>> g.close()

Don't know when ends one value and starts the next.